# Explanation of ratio and constructing a triangle with given ratio.

Tags: geometry

can anyone explain about ratio in some easy way and solve this problem??

- Construc a triangle, given the angle at the vertex, the base, and its ratio to one of the lateral sides??

I am taking a geometry class and the concept of ratio really confuses me.

Comment: Can you add a picture? At this time, the question is not clear.

Comment: @Sawarnik there wansnt any picture in the book. But it is related to Thales theorem which says that "For given angle, series of parallel lines divide each side into proportional parts."